# how to change a button variant which is in for loop in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, button

HTML:

```
<template for:each={accdata} for:item="acc">               
          <lightning-button key={acc.data.Id} class="slds-theme_brand" value={acc.data.Id} variant={buttonVariant}  label={acc.data.Name} onclick = {handleClick}></lightning-button>         
    </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api } from 'lwc';
export default class accData extends LightningElement {

accdata;

   @wire(getData, {accID: "$recordId" })
    accData({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    } else if (data) {
         this.accdata= data.map(item => {                
            return{
                data: item,
                buttonVariant: ''
            }
        }); 
    }

   handleClick(event){
        let dataSize = this.accdata.length;
        this.clickedRec =event.target.value;
        let objIndx = this.accdata.findIndex((item => item.data.Id === this.clickedRec));

        this.accdata[objIndx].buttonVariant='Brand';

        for (let i=0; i<dataSize; i++){
            if(i != objIndx){
                this.accdata[i].buttonVariant='neutral';
            }
        }       
    }
 }
```

when I click the button, since it's in for loop it's changing the variant for all the buttons that are in the loop, instead how can I just change the variant of the selected button in the loop. I have searched all possible blogs nothing helped, any suggestion is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'buttonVariant')  - this is coming , because array element is not there. Check you are having correct comparison like property name Id is correct or there is value in records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be another way to solve your requirement. What you can do is, add one more property `buttonVariant` in `acc.data` list after retrieving from server. Yor can add `data-id` property in button. This button data-id can be used to retieve current selected button id, then search that id in `acc.data` list and update `buttonVariant` property. Use this `buttonVariant` in variant={buttonVariant}.

As an example, you can do like this :

Html:

```
<template for:each={records} for:item="acc">               
      <lightning-button data-id={acc.Id} key={acc.Id} class="slds-theme_brand" value={acc.Id} variant={buttonVariant}  label={acc.Name} onclick = {handleClick}></lightning-button>         
</template>
```

Js Code:

```
@track records;
@track recordId;
    
@wire(getAccount, { accountId: '$recordId' })
wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
(data) {
        //this.records=data;
        let objs = [...data];
        objs.forEach(function (d) {
           d.buttonVariant='';
        });
        this.records=objs;
        }
}
    
handleClick(event){
    let selectedId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    let objIndx = this.records.findIndex((item => item.Id == selectedId));
    this.records[objIndx].buttonVariant='neutral';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dhanik, luckily this solution has helped me solve other problems, but did not solve the actual problem where I want to highlight the selected button. this is the error I am receiving

 [LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot add property buttonVariant, object is not extensible]]

I have updated my code in my question. Please let me know where am I going wrong,

Comment: I have little bit updated code to clone it first and then add property in it. Try this, if it will not work then we will do another approach.

Comment: Still the same error @Dhanik, looks like it's not able to provision new properties on this object.

Comment: Thank you @Dhanik, your approach has helped us fix the issue! I have modified my answer with working code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a selected property and/or something that can evaluate to a boolean property, then, simply use an `if:true` template directive to display your desired variant

[Render DOM Elements Conditionally](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_conditional)

Comment: Thank you @glls, but if I add a condition how can I change the button variant inside the loop, could you give me an example in this scenario please

Comment: if your condition is true, you render a button with a variant "x" otherwise variant "z". You just need to check against a bool property in your acc.data (if any) and then use the template directive. there is plenty of documentation and examples available online, if you are new to lwc, i would strongly suggest you go through the Trailhead modules on the subject.